# Postgres calculation running sum on large dataset

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to know how you would approach this issue with postgres.
Basically I need to keep track of the active products for each user (for simplicity I imagine there is only one user, but there will be thousands).
Imagine that I receive everyday the daily balance of active product and I store it in a table (mytable), here an example:

| day | user | dailybalance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan, 01 | userA | +1 |
| Jan, 02 | userA | +3 |
| Jan, 03 | userA | -2 |
| Jan, 04 | userA | +2 |
| Jan, 05 | userA | +1 |
| Jan, 06 | userA | -1 |
| Jan, 07 | userA | +3 |

(the information about the past days might potentially change, because of data corrections).

Now I need to calculate the running sum of active products (per user) for each day as running sum of the day before plus the dailybalance
I managed to achieve this with this query:

```
SELECT day, user , 
   SUM(dailybalance) OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY day) 
      AS runningtotal 
FROM mytable
```

And the results looks like this, in which the value is reflected into the runningtotal column

| day | user | dailybalance | runningtotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan, 01 | userA | +1 | 1 |
| Jan, 02 | userA | +3 | 4 |
| Jan, 03 | userA | -2 | 2 |
| Jan, 04 | userA | +2 | 4 |
| Jan, 05 | userA | +1 | 5 |
| Jan, 06 | userA | -1 | 4 |
| Jan, 07 | userA | +3 | 7 |

My issue is that to calculate this I need ALL the data since the beginning of times: I cannot do that because our data retention policy don't allow us to store this kind of data for long (in addition I don't think it scales when the dataset starts to be very large).

That's what I was thinking
Introduce a time filter and calculate/update the runningtotal, for example, only for the previous 3 days (and not only for the last day because, as I stated above, I might receive corrections for the past days).
In this way I might need to store the information about the runningtotal on the last day before the first day of my time filter.
Example: given the table above I want to (re)calculate the daily balance for the range Jan 5th - Jan 7th but I need somehow to retrieve the runningtotal of Jan 4th.
How can I do it?
And/or is there something in postgres that might be of help?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a table with the stored running totals, use `first_value()` to calculate the total stored in the previous row of the restricted window:

```
select day, user_, dailybalance,
       first_value(stored_total) over w
         - first_value(dailybalance) over w
         + sum(dailybalance) over w as runningtotal
  from mytable
window w as (partition by user_
                 order by day
          rows between 3 preceding
                   and current row);
```

Result:

```
 day        | user_ | dailybalance | runningtotal
 :--------- | :---- | -----------: | -----------:
 2021-01-01 | userA |            1 |            1
 2021-01-02 | userA |            3 |            4
 2021-01-03 | userA |           -2 |            2
 2021-01-04 | userA |            2 |            4
 2021-01-05 | userA |            1 |            5
 2021-01-06 | userA |           -1 |            4
 2021-01-07 | userA |            3 |            7
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=013ca404f2a7913f8846f2bde3c42eaa)

Comment: Hi Mike! First of all thanks a lot! Can you help me to understand a bit your solution? I'm playing with it and trying to define the restricted window (by date, for example specifying day > 2021-01-03) and get the stored total for (2021-01-02, the last value outside the window) but I can't. Maybe I need to store those values in a separate table?

Comment: @Gabriele If you store the running total for each day, then the running total for the previous day is `runningtotal - dailybalance`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much @Mike! So, what I am doing is using your query to update mytable's stored_total values, recalculating from a specific day. This will work for new record and also in case of corrections of the existing ones:

INSERT INTO mytable (day,user_, key_, stored_total)
(select day, user_, day||user_ as key_,
first_value(stored_total) over w
- first_value(dailybalance) over w
+ sum(dailybalance) over w as runningtotal
from mytable
where day >= '2021-01-11'
window w as (partition by user_
order by day
rows between 3 preceding
and current row))
ON CONFLICT (key_)
DO UPDATE SET stored_total = excluded.stored_total

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=087301569a03f27113431dfac214e155